# Symfony2, Doctrine data persistance

Tags: doctrine-orm, relationship

I have 5 tabels that have relationships.

Table User and Articles have relation:

In User:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="author")
 *      
 * @var ArrayCollection $articles
 */
protected $articles;
```

In Articles:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="articles")
 *
 */
protected $author;
```

I create new Article:

```
$article = new Article();
$article->setTitle("title");
$article->setText("Text test");
$article->setType("image");
$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

And I add Article to User:

```
$user->addarticle($article);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Article is saved in DB, but it don't have any data on field: `author_id`.

How to make relationship when I add an article to user to automaticaly in save in table Article to be `author_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this schema.
In User:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="author")
 */
protected $articles;
```

In Article:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="articles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $author;
```

Genereate entities, and update schema.

```
$article = new Article();
$article->setTitle("title");
$article->setText("Text test");
$article->setType("image");
$article->setAuthor($user);
$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```